# Opening .mobi files on Windows Phone 7 Kindle app

Tags: file-transfer

I need help on opening the .mobi file using the Kindle app on the Phone 7. I got a mobi file from a friend but can't figure out how to open it on my device.

No idea if someone who can actually do this

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately I don't have Kindle app on my WP7 phone because it is not available for my marketplace. But from my experience on Kindle 3 hardware reader and Windows Kindle app, you can send the .mobi file as an attachment to your @kindle.com email and amazon will take care of redistributing this file to all your Kindle reader apps.

If your document won't appear on your WP7 automaticaly, you can check your amazon account settings:

- Login to your amazon account, go to **Your Account** menu, select **Manage your kindle** option
- You will see list of all files that you have sent to your @kindle.com email
- On the end of each line is little button **Actions...**, click it and select **Deliver to my...**
- Dialog window will appear and you can choose to which from your kindle reader apps you want to deliver that document

[image: amazon kindle account settings]

Comment: There are also other ebook readers on the Windows Phone marketplace that you can download to read .mobi files

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible to get a @kindle.com address unless you have a hardware Kindle device.

Comment: .mobi files and Skydrive download? FastBookReader 2 It supports .mobi , .epub and .fb2 books,aswell as Skydrive and www downloads.

Comment: For your information Kindle for Windows Phone or Kindle for Windows 8 PC app do not support reading person document files since they do not have Kindle email address. All Kindle device, Kindle for iOs, except MAC app, Kindle for Android apps only have feature to access Personal docs. Thank you.

Comment: How can this answer have so many upvotes? This is an answer for the iOS and Android kindle apps and the hardware kindle, where this "deliver to" is available. The Windows Phone and Windows 8 kindle apps simply don't support personal documents yet, so you cannot open your own mobi files with it.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Phone and Windows 8 kindle apps don't support personal documents yet, so you cannot open your own mobi files with it. Neither with "deliver to" feature of the kindle website nor by sharing the file from a Windows Phone 8.1/Windows 8 file manager app.